# Java writer.write "\n"

Tags: java

Пытаюсь записать текст в .txt файл.
Хочу чтобы все строки которые я записываю начинались с новой строки.
Почему этот код не работает? Весь текст идёт в одну строку. (Write из FileWriter)

```
writer.write("Логин : " +list.get(0).getlogin() + "\n");
writer.write("Пароль : " +list.get(0).getpassword() + "\n");
```

Comment: в Блокноте смотрите?

Comment: Да, в блокноте.

Comment: О, через NotePad++ показывает нормально.
А что с блокнотом не так? :/

Comment: А Блокнот не поддерживает такие переносы. Обещали исправить в Windows 10, исправили ли — не в курсе

Comment: Неа, в 10 не исправили, в одну строку  - `echo -e "line1\nline2">tmp.txt | notepad.exe tmp.txt` -> `line1
line2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользователь @justcvb правильно объяснил причины происходящего в своём ответе. Один из способов решить эту проблему - использовать [форматтер](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) и спецификатор `%n`, подставляющий актуальный для данной системы символ перевода строки. Заодно это позволит улучшить ваш код, избавившись от конкатенации строк:

```
writer.write(String.format("Логин : %s%n", list.get(0).getlogin()));
```

Answer (score 8):

В разных операционных системах используются разные комбинации управляющих символом для перевода строк. Где-то это `\n`, где-то `\r\n`, как в Windows, где-то как-то иначе.

Метод `System.lineSeparator` возвращает соответствующий текущей системе разделитель строк.